# jQuery UI: Delay Loading AJAX Content Until Tab is Selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I'd like to know if there's a way to prevent content from loading until a tab is selected when loading the content via AJAX.

I'm not sure if this is already the case and if it is then great! That means no extra work!

Any help or answers are very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is an option for exactly that: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax

Answer (score 0):

You may want to event.preventDefault() in the show, select or load event if you are wanting to prevent further loading at some point in the chain of events. The jQuery UI Docs are the best source of information.